# What is the path to Internal memory on android phone?

Tags: applications, internal-storage, file-system, android-10

I'm trying to remove files from my Internal memory (which is 99% full).

In Big Files app, I can find large files, but unclear whether they are on the SD card on Internal memory.

E.g.,
I think this is the SD card:  /storage/emulated/

What is the /path/ to files (or directories) on the internal memory?

Comment: no `/storage/emulated/` is the emulated sdcard also avilable as `/sdcard` (internal flash memory). The real sd-card is called "external storage". The real sd-card is typically mounted on `/mnt/runtime/write/D123-7CAF` (the last hexadecimal folder is different for each sd-card). If you want to see the paths you can e.g. use [DiskInfo app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo).